# Pinch Zoom with ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, zooming, scrollviewer

I'm using an ScrollViewer in the MVVM enviroment to navigate around an map of europe. But when I use the ScrollViewer the deltaScale for the manipulationDeltaEventArgs.Pinchmanipulation doesn't work. The DeltaScale stays at one, no matter what. I tried to take a look at the Current and Original of the Pinchmanipulation and they are the same. So can anyone help me with making it possible to zoom while having an scrollViewer?

The manipulationDelta is:

```
public void Zoom(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PinchManipulation == null)
        {
            return;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think scrollviewer supports zooming in Windows Phone 8.  Only Windows Store apps can do this right now.

Comment: Pretty much got the same conclusion, but do you know a way to work around and implement a zoom function yourself with the scrollviewer?

Comment: It's kind of tricky, but I use a ViewportControl (not ViewBox) inside of a ScrollViewer.  The scrollviewer must have its ManipulationMode set to Control.  

Here's why it's tricky: if the content of the ViewboxControl is bigger than the ViewboxControl dimensions (the visible part), then the ViewboxControl will swallow all manipulation events.  This is fine if you are zooming. The ViewboxControl will act as your ScrollViewer.  When you are NOT zooming, you need to make sure that the ViewboxControl is the same size as its content so that it will pass the Manipulation events to the ScrollViewer.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to implement your own pinch/zooming with whatever control you want to use as a base inside the Scrollviewer/ViewportControl.  Search for Basic Lens sample and look at the MediaViewer control inside.  That might give you some clues.

On second thought, maybe you should forget about the Scrollviewer and just use the ViewportControl.  My implementation was a little too specific.